# Azure StorSimple virtual Array device says Provisioned or Remaining Capacity is Zero Bytes

Tags: azure, azure-storage

[image]

As i'm getting this capacity issue, I'm not able to add volume. When I try to add a volume it throws error as select a range between 500gb and above, when i do that it throws another error as mentioned size is larger than space available where my available size shows ZERO bytes.
Images added for reference.

Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you please open a support ticket for your issue if you have not done so already?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storsimple/storsimple-virtual-array-log-support-ticket

StorSimple virtual array needs to be assigned a data disk to store the local cache and it appears that something may be wrong with your local data disk configuration.

Comment: Sorry for late response. I was just evaluating the service and my subscription doesn't have any support plan. I didn't find any solution to query but I deleted the device from portal and VM as well and again followed the same steps to which I succeeded. Further exploring the service, using iScsi initiator I added volume to 2 of my system but I guess the Data was not replicated on real time. So can you tell me when does the data go into Azure? Does it go only while taking Backup?
Thanks in advance.